# How can I implement 5 dimensional array in one for loop in julia?

Tags: arrays, loops, julia, dynamic-arrays

```
function prealloc()
    situation=zeros(Int64,3^5,5);
    i=1;
    for north=0:2
        for south=0:2
            for east=0:2
                for west=0:2
                    for current=0:2
                        situation[i,:]=[north, south, east, west, current]
                        i+=1
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    situation
end
prealloc()
```

How can I implement this code on one for loop 
or in only one loop
how I use nested loops to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine the for loops into one loop with multiple variables.

```
function prealloc()
    situation=zeros(Int64,3^5,5);
    i=1;
    for north=0:2, south=0:2, east=0:2, west=0:2, current=0:2
        situation[i,:]=[north, south, east, west, current]
        i+=1
    end
    situation
end
```

Comment: the funny that i already tried that but didn't work ,but it work now thanks